# Redirecting Users to Login Page

Tags: php

I have been coding a content-based website. I want to lock some hyperlinks with a username and password.

For other open links I used:

```
echo '<a href='news1.php?id=$id>'.$row['heading'].'</a>';
```

I want the users to click on the links, which will redirect them to the login page.

Comment: So where is the code???

Comment: Please post the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

You have missing the single quote in your string.

Try this

```
echo '<a href="news1.php?id='.$id.'">'.$row['heading'].'</a>';
```

Comment: I have done this. It is working fine. But, I want the visitors to be redirected to the login page, when this link is clicked.

Comment: At the file news1.php you need to redirect it login page url

Comment: You need to add redirect a the **news1.php** file at top like

header("Location: http://example.com/login.php");
die();

Comment: I want to redirect when the link is clicked. ( As an event).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any php framework, it yes, it has the mechanism to redirect a user to the login page if he has not logged in. If you are not using frameworks, then you should check user's login status (probably in news1.php) when they click the above link and redirect to the login page if they've not logged in.

```
// in news1.php (if you are not using a framework )
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: No, I do not want to use any framework, as it is fine without it.

Comment: I see your point, then in your news1.php, you should place a redirect line: header('Location: '.$newURL);

Comment: If the above answer did not suit you.  I need more details in what you're doing. I dont' get what you're trying to achieve. Because if you just need a redirection, just do as my above answer, it's would make a good redicrection. So, what kind of application are you working on? Is it just a simple pure php only app? Can you write code to determine if a user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating a session when a user logs in, make sure to check for the session in news1.php. Something along these lines.

```
//in news1.php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['myuserloginsession'])){
//$newUrl would be your login page
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
}
```

[If isset $_SESSION goto this page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806098/if-isset-session-goto-this-page)